# system constantly wakes from Windows hibernation after installing Ubuntu in a dual boot with Windows 10?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows, suspend, hibernate

I've recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS in a dual boot setup with Windows 10.

Since installing this, though, whenever I'm on Windows 10 and set my computer to hibernate, it wakes up after about 5-10 minutes. I've checked my wake settings in Windows 10 and it's only set to wake with mouse or keyboard input and it was hibernating correctly before installing Ubuntu, so I don't believe it's a Windows issue.

I'm aware of how to change the wakeup settings within Ubuntu, but I have a feeling it may have something to do with the GRUB bootloader's wake settings? Because when it wakes from hibernation it goes first into GRUB before booting to Windows (I've changed the GRUB default to boot to Windows).

I'm wondering if it seems reasonable that some GRUB setting is causing my machine to wake from hibernation? And if so, there is any way to change the wakeup settings for GRUB so that it will only wake up with mouse or keyboard input??

I can't get my head around how to do this, since GRUB is still new and confusing to me!

Thanks for any assistance!